# Trouble starting rails server upon fresh RVM install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I just installed a fresh version of Ruby 1.9.2 via RVM on Mac OSX 10.7. I've activated 1.9.2 and my system seems to recognize ruby/gem/rails:

```
which ruby  => /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
which gem   => /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem
which rails => /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rails
```

I've bundle install'ed my existing rails app. No errors upon gem installation. Everything comes up on 'gem list'. However, when I try to bootstrap the app with 'rails server', I get the following error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- sass/rails/version (LoadError)
```

Full trace: https://gist.github.com/1215816

Again, sass and rails are installed:

```
gem list | grep sass => sass (3.1.7)
gem list | grep rails => rails (3.1.0)
```

I'm not sure what the 'version' part is about. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't have the sass-rails gem installed. That must have been what the error was trying to communicate. Working now!

Comment: perhaps just putting `  gem 'sass-rails'  ` in your Gemfile would resolve your issue